# Ionicons name for flexdashboard

Tags: r, icons, flexdashboard

I want to use ionicons icons when building a dashboard with `flexdashboard`.
From documentation ( https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#icon-sets )an example:

```
“ion-social-twitter”
```

When i search for same icon in iconicons website ( https://ionicons.com/ ) I get

```
<ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
```

If in my R code I insert "ion-logo-twitter" it doesn't work. What's the correct name for icons of this website? Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to add the icon? To the navbar? A valueBox? A page icon?

Comment: A valuebox ....

Answer (score 5):

I had a [similar icon issue](http://[(https://community.rstudio.com/t/unclear-ionicons-prefixes-and-limited-font-awesome-icons-in-r-markdown/36012)][1]) with my R Markdown site. The explanation is that R Markdown is operating with an outdated version of ionicons (v2), which uses a different naming convention.

If you use the **v2 ionicon names**, found at https://ionicons.com/v2/cheatsheet.html, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to tell without more code, but the following should work:

````
---
title: "Column Orientation"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```    

Column
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1

```{r}
valueBox(42, icon = "ion-social-twitter")
```

Column
-------------------------------------

### Chart 2

```{r}
```   

### Chart 3

```{r}
````

[image: Picture]

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear, I apologize. In ionicons website if I search for twitter it shows me a twitter logo which name is "logo-twitter". I expected to see "logo-twitter" not "social-twitter" as a icon in R. If on ionicons I search for  the standard users logo it comes out an icon with name people. If i put "icon-people" in R it doesn't work